# fourier font and \nmid

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, fourier

The `fourier` package does not provide a `\nmid` command. Using the `\nmid` from `amssymb` looks very different from the fourier's `\mid`.

Is there a way to produce a "compatible" symbol in fourier?
The two vertical lines should have the same height and width, but the `\mid` should have some extra space as to match the `\nmid`'s width when they are typeset in two lines above each other, as shown below.

I tried importing both from `MnSymbol` but couldn't figure out how they are defined there in the first place.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[widespace]{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a&=b & v\mid\infty\\
  c&=d & v\nmid\infty
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility, superimposing a rotated minus to the vertical bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[widespace]{fourier}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\nmid}{} % a mock definition
\renewcommand\nmid{\mathrel{\mathpalette\thiel@nmid\relax}}
\newcommand{\thiel@nmid}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{40}{$\m@th#1-\mkern-3.5mu$}\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1|$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
v\mid\infty\\
v\nmid\infty\\
x_{\nmid_{\nmid}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I use first `\providecommand` to give a definition to `\nmid`, so the later `\renewcommand` will work in all cases.

[image]

I'm not sure you really want `\mid` to take as much space as `\nmid` other than in the supposedly rare cases when they must be aligned, so I believe it's best to define a new command `\wmid` for the “wide `\mid`”:

```
\newcommand\wmid{\mathrel{\mathpalette\thiel@mid\relax}}
\newcommand{\thiel@mid}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hphantom{\rotatebox[origin=c]{40}{$\m@th#1-\mkern-3.5mu$}}\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1|$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
```

(put this before the `\makeatother` in the above code). Then the code

```
\begin{align*}
v&\wmid\infty\\
v&\nmid\infty
\end{align*}
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks. But I also wanted the two symbols/commands (of course not the glyphs themselves) to have the same width for typesetting them directly above one another in cases etc., see the refined question.

Comment: @CarstenThiel I've added a wide version

Comment: thanks. I have those two cases side by side throughout my thesis. And with just amssymb they are in fact of the same width.